# Custom MySQL duplicate_key update queries

Tags: ruby, sql, ruby-on-rails, comparative-review, active-record

The goal is to create an activity or update its counter if it's already present. And to be super accurate, the code avoids race conditions with a custom `insert_on_duplicate_key_update` MySQL query.

All user activities are already preloaded, so in case the service knows that there was an existing activity it will just do an update counter+1 query. Additionally, the code has to check whether the given `activity_name` is valid, which it does by specifying validators on the Activity `ActiveRecord` class.

How can these be cleaner?

#### B (code I am currently using)

```
class ActivitiesService
  def store_activity(activity_name)
    (activities[activity_name] || Activity.new(user_id: id, name: activity_name)).complete
  end
end

class Activity < Active::Record
  def complete
    return self.class.increment_counter(:count, id) if persited?

    insert_on_duplicate_key_update if valid?
    @new_record = false
  end
end
```

#### A (alternative rewritten code)

```
class ActivtiesService
  def store_activity(activity_name)
    if has_activity?(activity_name)
      Activity.increment_counter(:count, user_id)
    else
      Activity.complete(user_id: user_id, name:  activity_name)
    end
  end
end

clas Acttivity < Active::Record
  def self.complete(args)
    insert_on_duplicate_key_update if new(args).valid?
  end
end
```

Comment: Which version are you currently using in your implementation? Have you tested both of them to make sure they work the same way?

Comment: i'm using B now, as it fits more the ActiveRecord pattern. But ActiveRecord is not the cleanest pattern itself :) They both tested to work the same way

Comment: OK, I made an edit to your post to make that more clear. A vs. B questions are often not the best received on Code Review, as we prefer to review primarily your current code. I hope you get some good answers!

Comment: It is working and in production. This here is just pseudocode. `insert_on_duplicate_key_update ` stays actually for a custom sql query execution which performs an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... mysql query`